# Unable to push to gitlab from using pycharm ide

Tags: version-control, pycharm, gitlab

I have a project in Pycharm that I want to store in GitLab so as to be able to access it on different machines. I have tried pushing with version control but nothing happens even though it says completed and successfully.

I tried setting it from terminal but I could not figure it out.

Any help please?

Comment: Have you installed the required plugin?

Comment: I have an account on gitlab and I am trying to pass the email. That is what i usually do I cannot seem to understand what is the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First things first, you have to create a new project on GitLab.

Search for `plugins` in Pycharm's `settings` menu. Then, select `Browse Repositories` and install `GitLab Projects`.

You will then be prompted to restart Pycharm.

Now, once Pycharm is re-loaded, search for `GitLab Settings` in the `settings` menu.

Enter the URL `https://gitlab.com/` in GitLab Server Url

Now you have to fill in the `GitLab API Key`. To do this you have to paste in your `personal access token` provided by GitLab. If you do not know it, simply log into your `GitLab` account, go to `settings` -> `account` -> `access tokens`.

If you cannot see the token under Personal Tokens, simply create a new one (make sure you select for api). Copy the generated token key (you can only access it once I believe), and paste in the respective settings field as mentioned earlier.

Hit apply and ok, and you are set to go.

Now since you already have a project that you want to commit, open terminal and paste:

```
git config --global user.name "Your USERNAME"
git config --global user.email "Your EMAIL"

cd existing_folder
git init
git remote add origin YOUR GITLAB URL
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin master
```

P.S you can find the above terminal commands from the main page of your GitLab project.

Then, if you refresh your GitLab page, you can now see your pycharm project.

To commit future changes, simply `right click` on the `directory`, and select `commit and push`.

Comment: What about all the temporary PyCharm files? Are they properly ignored / excluded from commits? I tried manual settings before and I've found it quite difficult to keep my repo clean, without all these gitlab's hidden folders and xmls.

Comment: Why do you have to use the command line for Gitlab? In github setup you don't have to do that, not very user friendly.

Comment: @MarkusBawidamann there exists software that offers a GUI for doing such work, but I find that with CLI you have more control.

Comment: I use the CLI all the time in Linux, I turn to Pycharm for the GUI, not the CLI.

Comment: Whatever floats your boat :)

Comment: Yeah, but in this case, Pycharm did not float the boat, it sunk on me wanting a working GUI for Gitlab and I got soaked ;-)